# How to return a string literal from a function

Tags: c++, string, literals, return-type

I am always confused about return a string literal or a string from a function. I was told that there might be memory leak because you don't know when the memory will be deleted?

For example, in the code below, how to implement `foo()` so as to make the output of the code is "Hello World"?

```
void foo (       )              // you can add parameters here.
{

}

int main ()
{
    char *c;
    foo (    );
    printf ("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if the return type of `foo()` is not void, but you can return `char*`, what should it be?

Comment: Your requirement that it returns `char*` instead of `char const*` effectively forces us to assume that a plain string literal won't suffice and thus `return "hello world";` is an invalid solution. What are your requirements on constness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming we cannot modify main. To get your program working without a leak, you need something to have static storage:

```
void foo(char*& pC)  // reference
{
    static char theString[] = "thingadongdong";

    pC = theString;
}
```

But really, this isn't very conventional C++ code. You'd be using `std::string` and `std::cout`, so you don't *have* to worry about memory:

```
std::string foo(void)
{
    return "better thingadongdong";
}

int main(void)
{
    // memory management is done
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

If you're wondering if something needs to be manually deallocated, it's being done wrong.

Comment: Not always. After all, std::string does the allocation manually.

Comment: Eh, when you're not in "library writing mode" I should say. :)

Comment: There we go. Much better. My opinion exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with using char *foo() { return "Hello World"; }, am I missing something?

Comment: I would use std::string as far as possible. All memory allocation taken care of. And if you do want formating like printf(), try boost::format together with std::cout.

Comment: @fd, you can't change the string literal and it triggers the deprecated conversion in '03 and is ill-formed in c++0x. `char*` indicates the OP wants to change the returned string. We can't be sure.

Comment: @Johannes, ah, as I see the question description didn't seem to show the need for a mutable string.  I note your entirely correct comment about const-ness on the question, but I wonder if the OP didn't intend that restriction.  The question seemed to be more concerned with worrying about a memory leak from returning a literal, I suspect the informative answer is to explain the difference between returning a literal (with const declaration) and returning a mutable string whose length and/or lifespan should be managed.

Comment: Speaking of conventional C++ code, the `void` in the empty parameter list is redundant.

Comment: Not that I would want to optimize before it's needed, but does your "conventional C++" example copy the actual characters, or return an address to the static string literal? To avoid copying, `static std::string my_string = "better thingadongdong"; return my_string`, with return type `const std::string&` should be fine, right?

Answer (score 9):

Since the old use of char* is being deprecated, can you not simply use a string?

`const char* func1 () {return "string literal";}`

`string func2 () {return "another string literal";}`

Both of these work fine, with no compiler warnings.

However

`char* func3 () {return "yet another string literal";}`

will not compile at all.  Nor will

`char* func4 () {return &"a ref to a string literal?";}`

Stroustrup says in "The C++ Programming Language" (Third Edition):

"A string literal is statically allocated so that it is safe to return one from a function.

```
const char* error_message (int i)`
{
//...
return "range error";
}
```

The memory holding *range error* will not go away after a call of error_messages()."

So every string literal in a program is allocated in its own little piece of memory that lasts for the duration of the program (i.e. is statically allocated).
Putting the const in front of the char* lets the compiler know that you do not intend (and cannot) alter that string literal's little piece of memory which could be dangerous, so they let this assignment slide despite that conversion from string literal to char* is deprecated.

Returning instead to a string must copy the string literal into an object of type string, memory that the caller is responsible for.

Either way there are no memory leaks: every string literal gets its own piece of memory that is cleaned up on program termination; return to const char* returns a pointer to a literal's piece of memory (knowing you cannot alter it); and return to a string makes a copy into a string object existing in the caller's code which is cleaned up by the caller.

Though it seems a little ugly notation-wise, I'm guessing they left the const char* to keep the cheap alternative (involving no copies).

Answer (score 4):

> I am always confused about return a string literal or a string from a function.

**Immutable, literal string**

As I understand it, you are safe to return a string literal directly if the return type is declared const, to declare that the string is not intended to be altered.  This means you needn't worry about the lifespan of the string / memory leaks.

**Mutable, non-literal string**

However, if you need a string that you can change in-place, you need to consider the lifespan of the string and the size of the memory allocation in which it is stored.
This becomes an issue, since you can no longer blithely return the same memory containing string for each invocation of the function, since a previous use could have altered the contents of that memory, and/or may still be in use.  Hence a new piece of memory must be allocated to hold the string returned.

This is where the potential for a leak occurs, and where the choice needs to be made about where the allocation and de-allocation should occur.  You could have the function itself allocate the memory and state in the documentation that this happens and stipulate therein that the caller has to free the memory when it is no longer required (preventing a leak).  This means the function can simply return a char *.

The other option is to pass in some memory to the function that was allocated by the caller, and have the function place the string inside that memory.  In this case, the caller both allocates and is responsible for freeing that memory.

Finally, I mentioned that the size of the memory and string need to be managed when using a mutable string.  The allocation needs to be both large enough for the string initially set by the function and also for any changed that are made after the function, before the memory is freed.  Failing to do this correctly can cause a buffer overflow by writing a string to long to fit in the memory initially allocated; this is extremely dangerous to the health and security of your program.  It can cause bugs and security holes that are extremely hard to spot (since the source of the error - the overflow - can be far removed from the symptoms seen when the program fails).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
void foo(char ** pChar)
{
    // Make sure the string is shorter
    // than the buffer
    *pChar = new char[256];
    strcpy(*pChar,"Hello World!");
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
foo(&c);
```

As mentioned in the comment, be careful the string you are storing is smaller than the buffer or you will get a... stack overflow! (Pun intended)

Comment: You can't dereference `0` That'll crash your program.

Comment: Because the allocation is being done in `foo` When `foo` returns, the memory allocated will be dangling. (And there will be no way to free it.)

Comment: @George: That's the point. Don't take a pointer, take a reference. This is C++.

Comment: @GMan that's like saying "and if i do string(0)?" or "and if i do printf(0)?". He forbids null pointers as a precondition, so passing `0` is not allowed.

Comment: @litb: But a reference enforces that, rather than just saying "don't do it".

Comment: @GMan ah, i see. Yeah references seem the better tool here.

Comment: why enforce a double pointer? In this case you could just do `char* foo() { char* tmp = new char[sizeof("hello world")]; strcpy(tmp, "hello world"); }` if you ***really*** wanted to do this that way